# 2012 Automatic Civic firing wrong

Tags: honda, civic, emissions

I had a question for you all if you'd please help me out. My 2012 automatic civic had its emissions light, VSA light and high temperature lights turn on after I scraped the back rear end on a curb. The exhaust shakes more audibly than before, I have to give more gas to drive, and I can feel vibration while driving or idling the car. My emissions light starts blinking after 10 secs or so idling or driving so I haven't gotten the codes for repair yet.

I checked my transmission fluid and it is low. I'm also due for an oil change and battery change. My question for you all is where should I check to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you hit the exhaust when you were backing up? If so, it could have caused damage which would cause at least one of the codes you show above to pop (emissions, depending on which code it is). If you have the exact codes, that may be helpful to us.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if some auto parts stores allow you to take a code scanner home with you and return?

Comment: You could give them a call and see. I'm sure it would depend on the parts store. I'd just suggest to give them a call and see if they'll do it.